# android with loopback: confusion about sending notifications to devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using strongloop's loopback as server part, and I am writing two android apps, one for clients and one for shop owners.

When an order comes in, a notification should be sent to the shop owner's device.

So far, I learnt:

- I need to register to Google Cloud Messaging GCM
- loopback has libraries to connect to GCM

Now, loopback's documentation says it has a push-connector which does the connection.

But I am confused:

- Can I use loopback's push connector **alongside** my server app?
- Or do I need to implement that push connector inside my server app (otherwise how would my server app communicate with the push connector?)

Comment: This may sound confusing to you too...I am actually understanding that the push-connector is actually a stand-alone server...